# VirtualizingStackPanel error due to changing screen resolution and scale

Tags: c#, .net-core, datagrid, wpf-controls, ui-virtualization

I'm writing a WPF net 5.0 application, interface have a VirtualizingStackPanel for view many and many elements in GridView and of course their virtualization.

It's all okey, but ever I change the screen resolution or scale I get next error (it' ease to reproduce if you have two different screens with different scale):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot call StartAt when content generation is in progress.
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.GenerateBatches()
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size constraint, Nullable`1& lastPageSafeOffset, List`1& previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Nullable`1& lastPagePixelSize, Boolean remeasure)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.ArrangeElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
```

I know net 5.0 is out of support now, but maybe someone know good solution of the problem?